# How are integers alloted memory in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;    

int main() {
    int buf[2];
    buf[0]=65,buf[1]=66;
    char *p=(char*)(&buf[0]);
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
        cout<<(int)*(p+i)<<" ";
    return 0;
}
```

I was trying to understand the memory allocation using above code. The output of the above code is:

```
65 0 0 0 66 0 0 0
```

Why are all the values 0 except for 'p' and 'p+4', when 'p+1', 'p+2','p+3' represent the 1st integer block containing 65 and 'p+5', 'p+6','p+7' represent the 2nd integer block?

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It depends on the platform. Looks like on your platform an `int` is 4 bytes.

Comment: Use larger numbers for your test.

Comment: There is no dynamic allocation in your code.

Comment: look at the first diagram in this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: `char *p` itself does not allocate the memory itself. It just copies the address of `buf` in your code.

Comment: Use `reinterpret_cast< char * >` (C++) instead of `(char *)` (C), and be aware that, strictly speaking, this is broken code / undefined behavior. You are allowed to *copy* from `T*` to `unsigned char *` and back, but you are not allowed to *reinterpret* it like that. It works, most of the time, but be aware that it does not have to.

Comment: @DevSolar: `char&` is allowed to alias, and the intent (if not the current wording) is to allow pointer arithmetic within the object identified by the pointer prior to the cast.

Comment: @DavisHerring: Would you mind joining [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241994/on-char-aliasing) to elaborate on this?